# Flutter - Stream not returning data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a document collection called posts_favorites, which stores the reference to all the Posts that a user has bookmarked. The posts_favorites collection look as follows:

[image]

I have created a Stream to get all posts references that belong to a specific user, then I want to get the Post documents from the posts collection using the posts references.

I created a Stream to produce the data I need, but I am not getting any data returned from my Stream. Here is my code for the Stream:

```
  Stream<List<PostsRecord>> getFavoritePostsStream() async* {

List<PostsRecord> myList = [];

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("posts_favorites")
    .where("user", isEqualTo: currentUserReference)
    .get()
    .then((favoriteList)  {

        favoriteList.docs.forEach((element) async {

          String documentPath = element['post'].toString();
          var start = documentPath.indexOf("/");
          var end = documentPath.indexOf(")");
          var documentRef = documentPath.substring(start+1, end);

          //DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentPath);

          DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc(documentRef);
          await docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
              print('Document exists on the database');
              PostsRecord postsRecord = PostsRecord.getDocumentFromData(
                  documentSnapshot.data(), element['post']);
              //return myList.add(postsRecord);
              //print(postsRecord);
              return postsRecord;
            }
          });
        });
    });
}
```

I know this function works because the commented code produces the Post Records that I expect to get from Firestore.

I am not sure how to get the Stream function to return data that I can use in the Stream.

Thank you

Comment: `getFavoritePostsStream` does not produce any data because you are not calling `yield ...` anywhere inside it, more: [Creating a stream from scratch](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#creating-a-stream-from-scratch)

Comment: @ramluro Can you confirm if the above comment helped you. Were you able to resolve the issue by adding yield?

Comment: @ramluro Were you able to solve the issue? I think the comment by pskink is helpful. Please confirm if you have resolved the issue, if not we can further proceed with the case.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra - I was not able to solve the issue using Streams, so I took another route by calling a function that loads the data before building the widget. I am happy to share the approach that I used. Its not elegant, but it works

Comment: Please post the answer so that the community facing the same issues can refer your answer.